# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_bc\application\controllers\user.php on line 55

Tags: php, if-statement, social-networking

Im creating a social network site and trying to create a function that will only allow 18 and over to register to the site.  but I am getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_bc\application\controllers\user.php on line 55...any ideas guys?

```
function registration(){

//sets up captcha for regitration form
$vals = array(
    'img_path' => './captcha/', //Captcha image directory
    'img_url' => base_url().'captcha', //local save directory
    'img_width' => '275', // width of image
    'img_height' => '50', // height of image
    'expiration' => '7200' //Expiration of captcha set to 2 hours
);

$data['month'] = array(
    '1' => 'January',
    '2' => 'Febuary',
    '3' => 'March',
    '4' => 'April',
    '5' => 'May',
    '6' => 'June',
    '7' => 'July',
    '8' => 'August',
    '9' => 'Septemeber',
    '10' => 'October',
    '11' => 'November',
    '12' => 'December'
);
$excluded_days = array();
for($x = 1; $x <= 31; ++$x)
    (
    if(!in_array($x, $excluded_days))
    (
        $days[$x] = $x;
    )
)
$excluded_years = array();
for($x =date('Y')-18; $x >= data('Y')-100; --$x)
{
    $years[$x] = $x;
}
```

}

Comment: `for($x = 1; $x <= 31; ++$x)
    (` needs to have a `{` instead of `(` to enclose a block of code.  Same with the next `if`.

Answer (score 2):

You've used normal parentheses rather than curly ones for your `for` loop. Change them from `(` and `)` to `{` and `}` respectively.

This is also true for the `if` nested if statement and in fact any [control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php).

```
for($x = 1; $x <= 31; ++$x)
    { // <----- curly
    if(!in_array($x, $excluded_days))
    { // <----- curly
        $days[$x] = $x;
    } // <----- curly
} // <----- curly
```